# How to make items (columns) in <apex:pageBlockTable> hyperlink?

Tags: hyperlink, salesforce, visualforce, xmltable

I successfully created tables with style that salesforce provided. (like the one that highlighted on mouseover etc)

But I want the value of column to be a link to display detail info of the object.
When I don't create my own visualforce page, the table looks nice and the column
values (records) are all hyperlinked but can't figure out how to do it from visualforce apex code.

pageBlockTable and column definition does not seem to have attributes or anything that
make it hyperlink.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_column.htm

```
<apex:pageBlock title="test">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!workObj}" var="item">
        <!-- below needs to be hyperlink -->
        <apex:column value="{!item.name}" /> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I could achieve my goal by throwing the good design away like below but I would like to keep the code above.

This works but no salesforce style is applied.

```
 <apex:pageBlock title="my test title" >    
            <apex:dataTable value="{!workObj}" var="wn" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:facet name="header">仕事名一覧</apex:facet>
                    <apex:form >
                        <apex:commandLink value="{!wn.name}" />
                    </apex:form>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Why apex:commandLink and a form (!) in the column? What's wrong with simple <apex:outputLink value="../{!wn.Id}">{!wn.Name}</apex:outputLink>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `<apex:column value="{!item.name}" />`, try doing it like this in the column body:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="test">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!workObj}" var="item">
         <apex:column>
              <apex:outputLink value="{!item.name}">{!item.name}</apex:outputLink>
         </apex:column>
    <apex:pageBlock title="test">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!workObj}" var="item">
```